# DTO/ViewModel cómo mapear relación muchos a muchos de las tablas? Web Api Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, viewmodel

Estuve probando armar un DTO para una web api core con la relación de tablas muchos a muchos y no puedo hacer la navegación pasando por la tabla intermedia para armarlo.

Quiero listar para cada alumno el nombre del curso al que se inscribió.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Models

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
View Model, tal vez acá tenga que definir de otra forma nombreCurso, como lista, pero no me doy cuenta cómo hacerlo, quiero que me traiga para cada alumno los cursos en los que está anotado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controller, no puedo seguir navegando, entiendo que sería una lista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Enoces tu DTO debe tener un `List<string>Cursos` y harias un select para obtener solo el nombre. Es importante que agregues un Include a tu consulta ya que EF utiliza Lazy Loading y por tanto no vendrian los cursos.

tu consulta quedaria algo simailar a esto:

```
    var alumCursos = _context.Alumnos.Include( x => x.Cursos)
        .Select(a => new VMAlumCurso{
            Id = a.Id, 
            Dni = a.Dni, 
            Apellido = a.Apellido, 
            Nombre = a.Nombre,
            Cursos = a.Cursos.select(c => c.nombreCurso)
     });
```